# Get value of mysql table column depending on function

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a function **get_me()**. get_me() returns the slug of the page.

I also have mysql table **table**, which contains the following data, with columns **slug** and **block_to_echo** respectively:

```
----------------------------------------
|   slug    |       block_to_echo      |
----------------------------------------
| home      |  <b>Welcome</b> to home! |
| about     |  You're in about page!   |
| services  |  Services, <i>yes</i>!   |
----------------------------------------
```

Now, depending on get_me(), I want to get the value of block_to_echo, and yes, echo it.

For example, if **get_me()** returns services, I would like to echo "Services, *yes*!"

The function of get_me() has been defined. I only need to know how to get block_to_echo depending on get_me().

Apparently, I do not know how to code this one so I'm sorry if I can't provide a code.

Comment: But you know some of it, right?

Comment: Do you mean something like

    `$typ = get_me();

    mysqli_query($dbh, " SELECT block_to_echo FROM `table` where slug='$typ'");`
    
and then fetch and print the result?

Comment: Yes @flaschenpost..... something like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php    

$database_host='database host goes here. (use localhost if on the same machine)';
$username='database username goes here';
$password='database password goes here';
$database_name='enter the name of your database here';


$database=mysqli_connect($database_host,$username,$password,$database_name)or die("Error " . mysqli_error($database));
$query='SELECT block_to_echo from table where slug='."'".get_me()."'";
$result=mysqli_query($database,$query);
if(!$result){
//Error handling code here for issue with query
}else{
   //Everything went ok
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1){
      //There are no results for the value returned from get_me();
   }else{
      //We know we have at least one row. I'll assume it will only have a single row
      $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
      echo $row['block_to_echo']; //This should print the block to echo on the screen
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: gives me this error: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string

Comment: Turn on error reporting and make sure you have successfully connected to your mysql database by putting error_reporting(E_ALL); after the opening php tag. If it doesn't connect you should get an error.

Comment: ive turned it on.. no issue with connecting to database. i only get the mysqli_query() error..

Comment: Made an update to the code I posted. Copy and paste it exactly how I have it and just fill in the database username, password, etc. to match yours